# How do I remove old rcov results from Jenkins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rcov

When I first put my rails project in Jenkins, my settings were off and I generated reports for all code in `vendor/`. I've fixed my settings so new reports don't include that code, but even after wiping out my Jenkins workspace it still includes the `vendor/` code in every report.

How can I erase the old rcov statistics and track just my own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coverage statistics will fix themselves when all old builds that included them go away.